# Exception in Zend_Ldap when searching for a CN

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, ldap, openldap

I am experiencing a weird issue with Zend_Ldap (Zend_Framework 1.12) and PHP 5.6.24 on Windows 2012 R2 when searching for a CN. Basically, I send an LDAP search for the DN:

```
CN=ABUsers,CN=Users,DC=escenterprise,DC=net
```

after successfully binding with a valid LDAP user. That is confirmed by this Wireshark trace:

[image: WIRESHARK IMAGE]

What I find odd in the trace is that I get a proper response to my search query, which includes the users in the CN I am targeting. However, instead of returning that search result, the PHP LDAP extension (php_ldap.dll, v5.6.24.0) attempts 3 extra binds using the ROOT user for the following CN:

- CN=Configuration,DN=escenterprise,DN=net
- CN=DomainDnsZones,DN=escenterprise,DN=net
- CN=ForestDnsZones,DN=escenterprise,DN=net

Those binds appear to succeed; however the following extra searches for the 3 CN above all fail with the following error message:

```
0x1 (Operations error; 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090752, comment:
In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the
connection., data 0, v2580): searching:
(&(objectclass=user)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=ABUsers,CN=Users,dc=escenterprise,dc=net))
```

I understand that the 3 CN are contained in the response to my first query. However, I am having some troubles to understand why the 3 extra searches occur in the first place, along with the 3 binds as ROOT.

The issue only happens in one test environment, which is configured the same way of my other test environments where everything works correctly, that is, Zend_Ldap does not return an exception performing the very same search and it does not search the 3 extra CN.
If this may help, the test environment where the issue occurs sits in a data center outside of the network where the LDAP server is located and it is connected to it by means of a VPN. The other test environments are in the same building as the LDAP server.

Any idea on why it is happening in that particular environment? How can I avoid it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing this issue with a test environment that sits in one of my data centers.  It turned out to be my PHP Settings was changing optReferrals to TRUE.  This worked in the local environments but not for anything that sat outside of my network.  After making sure the setting defaulted to FALSE, it worked correctly and I did not see any "ROOT" binds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant! Turning off optReferrals fixed my issue too. Thanks a lot!